# Find common sub string from the list of strings

Tags: string, list, python-2.7

How can I take out only a prefix of a string from the list of strings? The caveat is that I do not know the prefix before hand. Only through this function, I will know the prefix.

```
(eg):
string_list = ["test11", "test12", "test13"]
# Prefix is test1
string_list = ["test-a", "test-b", "test-c"]
# Prefix is test-
string_list = ["test1", "test1a", "test12"]
# Prefix is test1
string_list = ["testa-1", "testb-1", "testc-1"]
# Prefix is test
```

In case there is nothing common in all the strings of the list, it should be an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

This function works:

```
def find_prefix(string_list):
    prefix = []
    for chars in zip(*string_list):
        if len(set(chars)) == 1:
            prefix.append(chars[0])
        else:
            break
    return ''.join(prefix)
```

### Tests

```
string_lists = [["test11", "test12", "test13"],
                ["test-a", "test-b", "test-c"],
                ["test1", "test1a", "test12"],
                ["testa-1", "testb-1", "testc-1"]]


for string_list in string_lists:
    print(string_list)
    print(find_prefix(string_list))
```

Output:

```
['test11', 'test12', 'test13']
test1
['test-a', 'test-b', 'test-c']
test-
['test1', 'test1a', 'test12']
test1
['testa-1', 'testb-1', 'testc-1']
test
```

### Speed

It is always fun to time things:

```
string_list = ["test11", "test12", "test13"]

%timeit get_large_subset(string_list)
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.3 µs per loop

%timeit find_prefix(string_list)
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.19 µs per loop

long_string_list = ['test{}'.format(x) for x in range(int(1e4))]

%timeit get_large_subset(long_string_list)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.44 ms per loop

%timeit find_prefix(long_string_list)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.38 ms per loop

very_long_string_list = ['test{}'.format(x) for x in range(int(1e6))]

%timeit get_large_subset(very_long_string_list)
1 loops, best of 3: 761 ms per loop

%timeit find_prefix(very_long_string_list)
1 loops, best of 3: 354 ms per loop
```

Conclusion: Using sets in this way is fast.

Comment: Nice way to use set to check whether the (character) list elements are same.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this,

```
def get_large_subset(lis):
    k = max(lis, key=len) or lis[0]
    j = [k[:i] for i in range(len(k) + 1)]
    return [y for y in j if all(y in w for w in lis) ][-1]

>>> print get_large_subset(["test11", "test12", "test13"])
test1
>>> print get_large_subset(["test-a", "test-b", "test-c"])
test-
>>> print get_large_subset(["test1", "test1a", "test12"])
test1
>>> print get_large_subset(["testa-1", "testb-1", "testc-1"])
test
```

Comment: This will throw a list index out of range error, if the list is smaller than the maximum length of the string within. Like `get_large_subset(["testt1", "testt2"])`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.. It's working fine for me too :-)

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner (with imported `itertools as it`):

```
''.join(x[0] for x in it.takewhile(lambda x: len(set(x)) == 1, zip(*string_list)))
```

Join a list of all first letters that are common to all members of `string_list`.